# Search and replace image urls in posts

Tags: images, urls

I'm struggling with my recently imported posterous data. All the image urls in the imported posts looks like this:

```
http://getfile1.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-03-30/kBpHaviyoumcvCEHnGnrDfwHwmJIrnqrHrxhCnHwfBIHuDsxbemHlxwEwCdi/IMG_6870.jpg
```

Now I tried to search and replace them with the [Search and Replace Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/), but it looks like it doesn't work with placeholders like:

```
http://%.posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/temp-2013-03-%/%/
```

Has anybody any idea how i can get an url like above into:

```
http://my.domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/IMG_6870.jpg
```

I'm able to execute SQL as well, if this helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have access to the database, you could do a search and replace there.

Comment: Yes but how do I search and replace in SQL with placeholders for ``getfileX``and the ``temp-YYYY-MM-DD``and the hash?

Comment: Have you already taken a look at [other questions like yours](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=search+replace)?

Comment: Yes I did, do you see one that helps me?

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't solve it with a plugin or plain SQL, see this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997954/find-and-replace-string-with-placeholders-in-sql/21998359). Instead I exported all the posts with Tools > Data export > Wordpress and deleted the posts. Then I run this python script over the exported XML file and imported the update xml file again. Tadaa...

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'http://([^/]*)/getfile/files.posterous.com/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)')

f1 = open('input.xml', 'r')
f2 = open('output.xml', 'w')

for line in f1:
    f2.write(p.sub(r'http://my.domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/legacy/\4', line))

f1.close()
f2.close()
```